# insert data to last row (at bottom) in treeview tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

The last inserted data to tkinter treeview shown in first row in treeview but i want to it at last row (bottom) of the treeview, following are codes used,

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import ttk
import mysql
import mysql.connector
from tkinter import messagebox
import datetime
from datetime import date

trial=tk.Tk()
trial.title("Trial Balance")
trial.geometry("500x200")

tree=ttk.Treeview(trial)
tree['show']='headings'

tree["columns"]=("account", "group", "debit", "credit")

tree.column("account", width=150, minwidth=150, anchor=tk.CENTER)
tree.column("group", width=150, minwidth=150, anchor=tk.CENTER)
tree.column("debit", width=100, minwidth=100, anchor=tk.CENTER)
tree.column("credit", width=100, minwidth=100, anchor=tk.CENTER)


tree.heading("account", text="Account", anchor=tk.CENTER)
tree.heading("group", text="Group", anchor=tk.CENTER)
tree.heading("debit", text="Debit Amount", anchor=tk.CENTER)
tree.heading("credit", text="Credit Amount", anchor=tk.CENTER)

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", 
passwd="Abcd11",database="entry",auth_plugin="mysql_native_password")
cursor=mydb.cursor()
    
sql_query_01 = pd.read_sql_query ("SELECT * FROM ledger_list", mydb)
df_ledger = pd.DataFrame(sql_query_01, columns = ['group_name', 'ledger', 'db_name'])


rows = []
for a in range(len(df_ledger)):
     ld_name = df_ledger.iloc[a][2]
     account_name = df_ledger.iloc[a][1]
     group_name = df_ledger.iloc[a][0]
    sql_query_02 = pd.read_sql_query ("SELECT * FROM "+ld_name, mydb)
    df_01 = pd.DataFrame(sql_query_02, columns = ['voucher', 'voucher_type', 'v_date', 'ledger', 'side', 'amount'])

    balance=0
    bal=0
    for i in range(len(df_01)):
    
        if(((df_01.iloc[i][4]))=="DR"):
        
            balance=balance+((df_01.iloc[i][5]))
        else:
        
            balance=balance-((df_01.iloc[i][5]))
        
    if(balance!=0):
    
        if(balance>0):
        
            rows.append([ld_name, group_name, balance, bal])
            tree.insert('', i, text="", values=(account_name, group_name, balance, bal))
    
        else:
        
            rows.append([ld_name, group_name, bal, balance])
            tree.insert('', i, text="", values=(account_name, group_name, bal, balance))

df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=["Ledger", "Group", "Debit", "Credit"])

column_debit = "Debit"
column_sum_debit = df[column_debit].sum()

column_credit = "Credit"
column_sum_credit = df[column_credit].sum()

total_trial="Total"
grp_trial=""



tree.insert('', i, text="", values=(total_trial, grp_trial, 
column_sum_debit, column_sum_credit))

print(column_sum_debit)
print(column_sum_credit)

print(df)

tree.pack()
trial.mainloop()
```

The last inserted data to treeview that i want to at last row of treeview is
tree.insert('', i, text="", values=(total_trial, grp_trial,
column_sum_debit, column_sum_credit))

Comment: Use `insert('', 'end', ...)` to append data at the end.